# Dual booting Ubuntu on UEFI without USB

Tags: system-installation, uefi

I am wondering if it is possible to install Ubuntu on my Surface Pro 4 (UEFI, I have disabled secure boot) and dual boot with my pre-installed Windows 10. I don't have a USB drive or a disk and I am thinking of installing it directly from my hard drive.

Comment: It's not impossible theoretically, but you'll have to figure out how to boot from that ISO image, and it might not be trivial. Good luck.

Comment: Someone else can help you on the ISO issue.  But you can install the Dual booting by using a USB DVD rather than a USB pendrive.  The BIOS treats a `USB DVD` and a `USB drive` differently.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the MS Surface Pro 4 indicates that it has a USB port. Thus, I recommend you buy a USB drive, if you don't have one, and install that way. If that's really impossible, then this procedure *should* work, with some caveats:

1. Repartition the disk so that it has a partition for the Ubuntu installation `.iso` file (as big as or bigger than that file) *and* create all the Ubuntu partitions you eventually want.
2. Write the Ubuntu `.iso` file to the partition you created for it. In Ubuntu, you'd use `dd`, but as you can boot nothing but Windows at this point, you'll need to use something else. Perhaps [WinDD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/windd/) would work.
3. Download and install my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You must also install the ISO-9660 filesystem driver that comes with it.
4. Reboot to rEFInd. It should show the Ubuntu `.iso` image as a boot option.
5. Select the Ubuntu `.iso` image. It should boot and you should be able to install normally, with one caveat: You might want or need to tweak the partition type codes of some of the partitions you created earlier.
6. After you're done, you may want to delete the Ubuntu `.iso` partition or employ it in some other way (like as a swap partition).

The big caveat here is step #1. IIRC, Windows' partitioning tools will let you shrink an in-use partition, but I'm not 100% positive of that. Also, I've never tested this procedure. I know that various critical pieces of it work in other contexts, but I'm not sure everything will fit together in this exact procedure. For instance, I know that rEFInd, with its ISO-9660 driver installed, can boot an Ubuntu installer `.iso` file when written to a partition on a USB flash drive; but I don't know that it will work correctly from the computer's main disk, particularly when that's also the Ubuntu installation target.

Answer (score 1):

### Boot Ubuntu on Windows UEFI computer without USB or CD

- Use Windows Disk Management to create FAT32 partition 3GB or larger.
- Copy/Paste contents of ISO file to new partition.
- Reboot pressing F12 and select UEFI Ubuntu.
- Proceed to installation.

Comment: Rather strange thing is, this solution worked for me, but does not show the ISO on rebooting on an identical laptop for a coworker, what could the issue be that it does not show the new partition for my coworker?

Comment: Is he coworker using an older BIOS boot computer?

Comment: Bitlocker was not disabled on that drive